# Horde installation failure CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, webmail, horde

0

I'm trying to install the Horde Groupware Webmail Edition 5 on CentOS 7 following this documentation, installing horde with pear and the installation is failing on my step number 5.

1. pear channel-discover
2. pear.horde.org
3. pear install horde/horde_role
4. pear run-scripts horde/horde_role
5. pear install -a horde/webmail

Error I've:

```
[root@horde-test ~]# pear install -a horde/webmail
Unknown remote channel: phpseclib.sourceforge.net
Package "pear.horde.org/kronolith" dependency "pear.php.net/Date" has     no releases
Package "pear.horde.org/kronolith" dependency     "pear.php.net/Date_Holidays" has no releases
Package "pear.horde.org/Horde_Mail_Autoconfig" dependency "pear.php.net/Net_DNS2" has no releases
Package "pear.horde.org/Horde_Mapi" dependency "pear.php.net/Math_BigInteger" has no releases
horde/imp can optionally use package "channel://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/File_ASN1"
horde/kronolith requires package "pear/Date"
horde/kronolith can optionally use package "pear/Date_Holidays" (version >= 0.21.0, version <= 1.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 1.0.0alpha1)
horde/webmail requires package "horde/kronolith" (version >= 4.2.23,         version <= 5.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 5.0.0alpha1)
horde/Horde_Mail_Autoconfig requires package "pear/Net_DNS2" (version >= 1.3.0)
horde/imp requires package "horde/Horde_Mail_Autoconfig" (version >= 1.0.0, version <= 2.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 2.0.0alpha1)
horde/Horde_Mapi requires package "pear/Math_BigInteger" (version >= 1.0.2, version <= 2.0.0, excluded versions: 2.0.0)
horde/Horde_ActiveSync requires package "horde/Horde_Mapi" (version >= 1.0.0, version <= 2.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 2.0.0alpha1)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

And if I tried to install the requires packages I got this error:

```
[root@horde-test ~]# pear install Net_DNS2
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/Net_DNS2"
install failed
Any idea what is happening?
```

Thank you all

Comment: Have you condsider to try to install it via `yum`? https://kyup.com/tutorials/install-horde/

Comment: The horde package isn't available vi yum

Comment: Have you install `epel`? `yum install epel-release`

Comment: Yes, after install epel-release the horde is now installed but I can't find anywhere how I do the rest of setup. Any idea where I can find a document?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://www.horde.org/apps/horde/docs/INSTALL#configuring-horde

Comment: Thank you Romeo. I've tried to follow that document but seems is missing some configuration. For example I've created one database and one user on mysql server but then when I'm trying to login on my server http://your-server/horde/ the login fails... Seems the user can't login..